# Change the public directory of vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

After creating new project using the vue-cli I get a structure like this:

```
- wwwroot
- ClientApp
--- public
--- src
--- *.json // various config files
```

so what I trying to do is to change the public folder from `ClientApp/public` to `wwwroot`.

I created a new config file `vue.config.js` that looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
        .tap(([options]) => [Object.assign(options, {
            template: '../wwwroot'
          })])
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: Child compilation failed:
>     Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/aaa/Projects/bbb/ccc/wwwroot' in '/Users/aaa/Projects/bbb/ccc/ClientApp':
>
> Error: Can't resolve '/Users/aaa/Projects/bbb/ccc/wwwroot' in '/User  s/aaa/Projects/bbb/ccc/ClientApp

I understand that it's trying to find **wwwroot** in **ClientApp** (which is not there, they are in same folder) but I don't know how to make it to search for **wwwroot** in **/Users/aaa/Projects/bbb/ccc/** folder.